# Converting a nested for loop from MATLAB

Tags: programming, coding-style

In MATLAB I have the following series of nested `for` loops that update a matrix. (It's not my code, but someone else's that I'm trying to replicate - I don't know why `i` starts at 0, for example, and I don't think it needs to, since `k` can be specified by the user.)

```
[n,d] = size(var1);
for i = 0:k
    for j = 0:k
        var1(i+1,d-j) = var1(i+2,j+2);
    end
end

for i = 0:k
    for j = 0:k
        var1(n-i,j+1) = var1(i+2,j+2);
    end
end

for i = 0:k
    for j = 0:k
        var1(n-i,d-j) = var1(i+2,j+2);
    end
end
```

`k` is some variable that is less than both `n` and `d`. In terms of size, `k` is about 100 and `n` and `d` are about 1000.

I've had a look over the Q&A - [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica) - for avoiding/rewriting nested loops.

However, I'm not sure what to do to apply that guidance here. I think I'm being confused by the reference to `(i+1,d-j)`. The non-Mathematica part of me wants to use nested `For[]`s and `Part[]`s, but that can't be the best/fastest/most efficient way, certainly with the sequence of them shown above.

Here's a basic example...

```
var1 = RandomInteger[{0, 5}, {1000, 1000}];
{n,d} = Dimensions[var1];
k = 100;
```

Comment: Never use `For` unless you *know* you need `For`.  `Do` gives you the same in a more readable and safer (localized iteraror) manner.  As a first step, I'd translate the code as is using `Do` and would only think about using alternatives later.

Comment: No need to abstain from `Do`/`For` if you're in the mood. If you're after a serious optimization,  some more background/motivation may be useful.

Comment: Ah yes `Do` is a first step. In terms of size, `n` and `d` are probably ~1000, and `k` ~100, so the matrix isn't *huge*. I'll update the question a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First step: convert the code without modifications.  This is the safest (we don't want to accidentally break the algorithm):

```
{n, d} = Dimensions[var1];

k = ...

Do[
 var1[[i + 1, d - j]] = var1[[i + 2, j + 2]],
 {i, 0, k}, {j, 0, k}
]
```

Next step:  It looks weird to me that the iteration starts from 0, as both Mathematica and MATLAB index from 1.  (Understanding the problems the code solves would help here...)

```
Do[
 var1[[i, d - j + 1]] = var1[[i + 1, j + 1]],
 {i, k + 1}, {j, k + 1}
]
```

Next step: figure out whether any element of `var1` that has already been modified by the loop is being used for calculating another element.  This will tell us whether we can use `Table`.

It looks like row $i$ of the modified `var1` is computed based on row $i+1$ of the original `var1` (so we don't even have to think about $j$ any more).  An already modified value is never used in the computation of a new value.  This means we can use `Table` or other things that operate on immutable data.

If we look carefully, this code takes the square matrix `var1[[2 ;; k + 2, 2 ;; k + 2]]`, then flips it around horizontally and puts it back in a different position in `var1`.  We can do it like this:

```
var1[[1 ;; k+1,   d ;; d-k ;; -1]] = var1[[2 ;; k+2,   2 ;; k+2]]
```

I *think* this could have been written in the same way in MATLAB too ...  so at this point just choose whatever you find more readable.

---

Note: try to avoid `For` in favour of `Do` (and possibly `While`) unless it is clear that `For` is really the better solution.

```
For[i=1, i <= n, i++, doThis; doThat; makeResult]
```

is not very readable due to all those commas and semicolons and the possibility to mix them up. (When you see `;` in C code and you're tired it's all too easy to accidentally write `;` in Mathematica too, even if you know very well that Mathematica requires `,` there.) Also, it operates with a variable `i` that is *global*.

```
Do[doThis; doThat; makeResult, {i, n}]
```

is much more readable, can be trivially extended to multiple iterators, can easily be replaced by `Table` if that turns out to be better (while trying to make the code more Mathematica-like), and the iterator `i` is localized.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why the iteration starts at 0 either, it doesn't need to.

Comment: @blochwave That's why I don't like to translate code I don't understand.  For relatively simple code like this it's usually easier to understand the problem first, then re-implement it, than to blindly translate an algorithm when we don't know where it comes from.  Maybe the starting index of `0` makes sense for the physics (?) problem the code is solving.

Comment: I think it might indeed make sense as you say - I'm working through the code and the problem behind it myself at the moment, I was just getting stuck at the nested for loops and didn't know what to do next!

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm sure someone blindly translated it from C to MATLAB ;) ... and now to mma.

Comment: @rm-rf if they did, that's annoying (for the rest of the code) - I can do C ok, but not MATLAB!